# What does 改めて exactly mean?

Tags: adverbs

> 改めて すごい人だかり!

The character came out of the building to meet a journalist groups and says this. Why is 改めて used here? "Looking at it again"?

Comment: I think we would like to have more context to understand it precisely. It can mean something like "let me reiterate (slightly differently)", but in that case it might be important to understand what's being reiterated. Is it from manga or something?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this 改めて is like "I realize once again", "Let me say this again" or simply "Again". You say this when you re-experience or re-realize something.

Here's how this is defined by 明鏡国語辞典:

> ##### 改めて
>
> ❷思い直して感動などを新たにするさま。今さらのように。
> 「桜は美しいと改めて感じ入る」「合格の喜びを改めてかみしめる」